# Youtube API using unrelated worker?

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, youtube, worker

This is very weird. I'm using youtube JavaScript API to embed a playlist on my website. It would be all good except my recent check what's happening in my workers. It seems that the API decided to send it's messages to one of it.

here's the data which my worker is receiving.

```
bubbles: falsecancelBubble: falsecancelable: falsecurrentTarget: Windowdata: "{"event":"infoDelivery","info":{"currentTime":109.455757,"videoBytesLoaded":1,"videoLoadedFraction":1},"id":1}"defaultPrevented: falseeventPhase: 0lastEventId: ""origin: "https://www.youtube.com"path: Array[1]ports: Array[0]returnValue: truesource: WindowsrcElement: Windowtarget: WindowtimeStamp: 1428083437641type: "message"__proto__: MessageEvent
```

Also as I've seen in another question Youtube API does this

```
www-embed-player.js:167 GET chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
```

I wasn't expecting Google to create such faulty API. Is there a way to disable those things?

Answer (score 0):

Quick experiment rendered a solution. Moved all youtube code to a separate html and embedded in my parent page.

```
<iframe id="youtubePlayer" src="mediaPlayer.html">
```

You can still access youtube api from your main page like that

```
 var mediaPlater = document.getElementById('youtubeFrame').contentWindow.player;
   // i.e. skip to next video 
   mediaPlayer.nextVideo();
```

This solved totally unexpected worker activity. This console error remained but after reading that it's a won't-fix it doesn't bother me.

```
www-embed-player.js:167 GET chrome-extension://
```

Content of my mediaPlayer.html

```
<div id="ytplayer" class="musicPlayer"></div>
<script>
var player = null;
// Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/player_api';
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
// YouTube player after the API code downloads.
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
        height: '180',
        width: '280',
        playerVars: {
            autoplay: 1,
            controls: 0,
            listType: 'playlist',
            list: 'RD4-OlYiH1DXI'
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onError': function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    player.nextVideo();
                }, 200);
            }
        }
    });
}


function onPlayerReady() {
    // fixes firefox ignoring first onerror if the first video is faulty
    player.nextVideo();
}
</script>
```